# "5":"6789":"78" , how can we extract just the numbers as tokens

Tags: java, split, token, quotes

For example we have our data set like this "5":"6789":"78" ,  how can we extract just the numbers as tokens, we know how to split using colon, but there is problem to remove these quotes, after it is been transferred into the array, please suggest.

Comment: `replaceAll("\"","");` should do the trick to remove all quotes

Comment: @TheLostMind so?  I'm just stating how to remove quotes not how to split by colon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just split based on one or more non-numeric characters.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s ="5\":\"6789\":\"78";
    String[] arr = s.split("\\D+");// \\D+ splits the string based on one or more non-numeric characters.
    for(String str :arr){
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

O/P:

```
5
6789
78
```

Comment: sorry!! i get this error New.java:5: cannot resolve symbol
symbol  : method split  (java.lang.String)
location: class java.lang.String
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split("\\D+")));
                                        ^
New.java:5: cannot resolve symbol
symbol  : variable Arrays
location: class New
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split("\\D+")));
                       ^
2 errors

Comment: @DivyaNayak - Which version of java are you using?

Comment: @DivyaNayak - nevermind. Edited my answer to work with lower versions of java. Check my updated ansewr :)

Comment: so according to you there is no need of splitting based on : ??is the code given by you directly generate given o/p??

Comment: @DivyaNayak - `split()` method gives you a String array. in this case, the array arr has the the values 5, 6789 and 78 in indices 0,1 and 2 respectively. You will have to *parse* the string as an *integer* if you want to do some mathematical operations on it. You can check the output [here](https://ideone.com/1Fft5l) madamji

Answer (score 4):

You can either:

- Use `split(":")` and then use `replaceAll("\"", "")` on each entry;
- Else, use a regular expression such as `(\d+)` and use `Matcher.find()` to iterate over the numbers.

The first option is simpler to implement and easier to follow.

Comment: or use replaceAll("\"","") of the String data, then use split?

Comment: @user1354678: The replacing can take place before or after the splitting. I suggested to do it afterwards so that the OP can *continue* from where he/she currently is.